# Owning Side vs Non-Owning Side In hibernate and its usage in reference of mapped by element?

Tags: java, hibernate

I came across the terms i.e `owning side and non-owning` side while studying hibernate.For example :- here is
the statement regarding usage  of mappedby element in terms of its usage in one to one mapping

> If the relationship is bidirectional, the non-owning side must use the
>   `mappedBy` element of the `OneToOne` annotation
>   to specify the relationship field or property of the owning side.

But i did not get what actually `owning side and non-owning` side is?

Comment: You mean what does it do or the reason behind the name mappedBy? I put bellow an explanation for why it's necessary and why it's called like that, let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749689/what-is-the-owning-side-in-an-orm-mapping/21068644#21068644

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my understanding with simple example where College has many students(One to many relationship)

```
                       corresponds to       
College(Value Object) -----------------> College (Database Table)

                       corresponds to       
Student(Value Object) -----------------> Student (Database Table having column which is
                                                  foreign key to College table . 
                                                  So This is owning side and College  is
                                                  Non-owning side )
```

**In terms of Object representation, Student object is owning side becoz it will be having reference pointing to college column.So Student is owning side and College in non-owning side.**

**Usage of Owner side and Non-Owning side in hibernate in relation of mapped by element**

Non-Owning Side Object

```
@Entity
public class College {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int collegeId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="college") // here non-owning side using mapped by elment to specify
                                   // the relationship field of owning side
    private List<Student> students;
    }


Owning Side Object

@Entity
public class Student {
@ManyToOne
    private College college;
}
```

In conclusion the owning side is the entity that has the reference to the other. In terms of DB, it
translate to table entity  having column which is foreign key to column in other table like in
case of College has many students.

**Note:-** owning-side table must contain a join column that refers to the other table's id.It means owning side entity should contain @joincolumn annotation otherwise it will consider the name as primary key column name of other table. See [@OneToOne unidirectional and bidirectional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420916/onetoone-unidirectional-and-bidirectional)

Answer (score 7):

The idea of a owning side of a bidirectional relation comes from the fact that in relational databases there are no bidirectional relations like in the case of objects.

In databases we only have foreign keys, where only one table can have a foreign key to another. Let's take an example that would not work as expected and see why mappedBy is necessary:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSONS")
public class Person {
    @OneToMany
    private List<IdDocument>  idDocuments;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="IDDOCUMENT")
public class IdDocument {
    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;
}
```

This would create not only tables PERSONS and IDDOCUMENTS, but would also create a third table PERSONS_IDDOCUMENTS:

```
CREATE TABLE persons_iddocument
(
  persons_id bigint NOT NULL,
  iddocuments_id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_persons FOREIGN KEY (persons_id) REFERENCES persons (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_docs FOREIGN KEY (iddocuments_id) REFERENCES iddocument (id),
  CONSTRAINT pk UNIQUE (iddocuments_id)
)
```

Notice the primary key on documents only. In this case Hibernate tracks both sides of the relation independently: If you add a document to relation Person.idDocuments, it inserts a record in PERSON_IDDOCUMENTS.

If we change the Person of a IdDocument, it changes the foreign key person_id on table IDDOCUMENTS.

Hibernate is creating two unidirectional (foreign key) relations on the database, to implement one bidirectional object relation, because databases do not support bidirectional relations.

But what we want is for the object relation to be only mapped by the foreign key on table IDDOCUMENTS towards PERSON: one document belongs to only one person.

There is no need for the extra table, that would force us to modify both Person.idDocuments and IdDocument.person inside the same database transaction to keep the relation consistent.

To solve this we need to configure Hibernate to stop tracking the modifications on relation Person.idDocuments. Hibernate should only track the other side of the relation IdDocument.person, and to do so we add mappedBy:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
private List<IdDocument>  idDocuments;
```

This means "modifications on this side of the relation are already **Mapped By** by the other side of the relation IdDocument.person, so no need to track it here separately in an extra table".

This gives us the mapping we want, but has one major consequence:

- Modifications on the Person.idDocuments collection are no longer tracked by Hibernate, and it is the responsibility of the developer to modify IdDocument.person instead in order to modify the association.

Comment: Did this made sense, for the reason why mappedBy is necessary and the reason for it's name?

Comment: Your answer is great but suffers from poor formatting and certain hibernate concepts seem implied.
_so we add mappedBy_ -  you mention the annotation but not which table it is in, ..
_This means "modifications on this side of the relation_ - it's confusing which side
_Notice the primary key on documents only_ : in which table?

There are other typos too but if you format the answer, it would be a great answer. All the same, thank you for writing this. I have been looking for such an answer since a long time.

Comment: this same answer is answered by the same person in better format here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749689/what-is-the-owning-side-in-an-orm-mapping/21068644#21068644

Answer (score 4):

The 'owning'  side is the entity whose table will hold the reference.

If you have a one-to-one relationship between `EntityPerson` and `EntityAddress`, then, if `EntityPerson` is the owning side, it will have in its table something like

```
 ADDRESS_ID int NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Address (ID)
```

Comment: I was also under same impression. Please see my answer also