# JPA Unidirectional OneToOne FK in Child Table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got fk in child, but i need @JoinColumn in parent. By default, in OneToOne, joincolumn creates fk in parent table (where it is specified), i have existing tables with fk in child. (project new demands) Before it was mapped using mappedBy clause.

How can I use @JoinColumn for @OneToOne linking in the parent entity?

I want to make unidirectional relationship.

Why cant I use this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumn = "childs_fk")
```

ty!

### Update:

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054178/jpa-joincolumn-annotation-with-one-to-one-relationship) example FK column "WEBSITE_ID" would be in Player table. My FK is in Website table.

> In a bi-directional OneToOne relationship, a single foreign key is
>   used in the owning side of the relationship. On the other hand, the
>   target entity must use the mappedBy attribute.

I've got existing tables and my fk is not on the owner side, 
+ I know for a fact that FK could be on both sides. This answer is not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table Parent and one table Child and the foreign key is on the Child table with name PARENT_ID and pointing to the ID in table Parent then the annotation must look like:

```
@JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
```

Comment: There is a lot of FK's in child table beside the one I need. 
And it's name not in this format: 

Parent table is `inv_act_acceptance_items_mus`, 
Child table is `inv_book_museum`
Fk is in `inv_book_museum`, and named `act_item_id. `

So the only way is to rename it?

Comment: no no! this is just an example and the name must match your foreign key name

Comment: I meant renaming `act_item_id` to somethig like `inv_act_acceptance_items_mus_id`. Thanks!